# PHPMYADMIN rejected to user root with no pass : access denied

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

[image: AccessDenied.png[][1]]

[config.inc.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1I)

I checked the C:/xampp/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php file and tried changing my pass (because I have no password) according to my research. It did not work unfortunately.

Comment: create a user in mysql and pass that user details (username/pass) in phpmyadmin..or you can pass root user and its password..

Comment: where do i find the mysql? is it a file or an application and pls tell pathway starting from C: drive

Comment: what you want to do by connecting phpmyadmin....

Comment: Welcome to [SO]. The link to config.inc.php is invalid. It is also better to paste the actual text into the question rather than use an image of the text. Please use the [edit] button to correct the question so someone can provide you the answer you seek.

Comment: I'm afraid there are a few things about your question I don't understand. Were you able to connect successfully before you tried changing the password? How did you change the password? Did you update the new password in `config.inc.php`? Are you getting an error message now? Are you able to try connecting from the command line client; does that work?